# Which GenerationType is best among AUTO,IDENTITY & TABLE(or Any other best approch) using Hibernate persistence provider?

Tags: java, mysql, oracle, hibernate

In my project we are using Oracle and we want to give support for MYSQL also. Oracle have sequence support but MYSQL don't have. which GenerationType is good if we want to support ORACLE and MYSQL with same code base using Hibernate persistence provider among AUTO,IDENTITY & TABLE(or Any other way)?, can any one give brief description about these please?

```
Ex:
Class POJO{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
------
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
-----
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
------
(or Any other best approch?)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
@GeneratedValue(generator = GenerationType.TABLE)
```

It will work for both Oracle and mySql

Comment: Thanks for you reply udit Khare, but as per my knowledge it will effect performance. Is there any better approach?

Comment: When using MySQL DB, TABLE generator performs same as SEQUENCE generator. Since MySQL does not support sequences, it creates a sequence table to maintain a counter, which is similar to what table generator does.

Answer (score 0):

Since MySQL supports auto_increment use GenerationType.AUTO for its corresponding POJOs.

For the POJOs for Oracle database you could create a sequence for each and use it in your POJOs as illustrated below.

**Sequence creation**

```
 CREATE SEQUENCE MY_SEQ
 INCREMENT BY 1
 START WITH 1
 NOMAXVALUE
 NOCYCLE
 NOCACHE;
```

**Generation type**

I suppose the primary key is labeled ID in your Oracle table.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "mySeq")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "mySeq", sequenceName = "MY_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "ID")
private Long id;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but my question is different, same code base should work for both db's. I have to use any one Generator type.

Comment: I think in your case since you are manipulating data from different RDMS you must not use only one GenerationType.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into configuring all the database-dependant stuff in an xml configuration file. I haven't used xml files to configure hibernate for years and I've never mixed it with annotations. But the way I understand it: Your xml configuration will overwrite this specific configuration from your annotations in your POJO.

So you could leave your POJO with your oracle-specific ID Generator, and in case you deploy it for a MySQL, you would need to add an xml configuration with your MySQL-specific ID Generators.

I can't give you any details on this though. sorry.